# Calculating fairness in a competition across offices

Tags: analysis, statistics

We want to run a fitness competition in our company using pedometers to determine which office location is the healthiest. The problem is, we can't use total number of steps, because each office has a different number of employees. And you can't just take the average steps taken per employee at a given location, because it would be easy to cheat the system.

I'm sure the correct equation involves considering the total number of days in a month, and the total number of entries provided per location, but I'm certainly no math wiz (I barely even know what to tag this question with -- feel free to edit as necessary)...

And so I turn it over to the beautiful brains here....  Thanks and I love you in advance.

Update: Employees are only allowed to make one entry per day and are not required to make any entries at all.

Comment: Have you tried the median number of steps? More or less half the people at an office would have to cheat for it to really show.

Comment: I'll try that while I wait for additional comments/answers, thanks! I do think there ought to be a more precise option..

Answer (score 2):

A couple of suggestions:

You want a measure of how much walking the office is doing. So if you give all the employees pedometers and record how many steps they take, your results will be affected by:

- The number of employees in the office (more employees would mean more steps)
- How long they use the pedometer for (wearing the pedometer for two weeks would give twice as many steps as if you wore it for only one week, for instance)

So you should take the total number of steps from each office and divide it by: the length of time they had the pedometers (in days, say) and the number of employees in that office.

This will tell you the average number of steps per employee per day for that office.

You might also want to check for outliers in the data before you do this: look through the counts on each pedometer and see if they're significantly different to the rest of the data. If they are, you may want to *consider* removing these.

- It might be that one employee shook the pedometer to artifically give themselves a much higher reading (or it might be that they're super active!)
- It might be that some employees were off for most of the week and recorded very few steps.

If you do choose to ignore these, you'll get a better overall picture of each office. Make sure you divide by the number of employees you include, not the total number.

If you're very concerned about some employees cheating, you could ignore the bottom 25% of the data and the top 25% of the data from each office, then take the average of the rest.

Comment: Minor update to the question that I believe addresses some of your assumptions. I'll try to work with your suggestions in the meantime.